# Vim colorscheme background only applies to text

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

[image: pic]

As you see, the colorscheme only loads correctly until a certain point, at that point the background only applies to the text, the rest being black for some reason. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you running vim inside tmux?

Comment: Looks like a wrong value of `TERM`, what is it? Inside tmux, it should be `screen-256color`.

Comment: I was using gnome-terminal, but i no longre need ot figure it out, theme works on arch using RXVT-unicode